# Show the equivalence between two norms on $\mathcal{L}(E)\times \mathcal{L}(E)$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $E$ be a complex Hilbert space, $\mathcal{L}(E)$ be the algebra of all bounded linear operators on $E$.

Consider the following two norms on $\mathcal{L}(E)\times \mathcal{L}(E)$
$$N_1:=N_1(A,B)=\left\|A^*A+B^*B\right\|^{1/2}$$
and
$$N_2:=N_2(A,B)=\sup_{\substack{z_1,z_2\in \mathbb{C}^2,\\ |z_1|^2+|z_2|^2<1}}\left\|z_1A+z_2B\right\|.$$
It is not difficult to prove that
$$N_2\leq N_1.$$

> My goal is to find a constant $\alpha$ such that
>   $$N_2\geq \alpha N_1.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy to see that $F := \mathcal{L}(E) \times \mathcal{L}(E)$ is complete for $N_2$. Indeed, if $(A_n,B_n)$ is Cauchy for $N_2$ then by taking $z_1 = 1, z_2 = 0$ we see that $A_n$ is Cauchy in $\mathcal{L}(E)$ and hence converges to some $A \in \mathcal{L}(E)$. Similarly there is a $B$ such that $B_n \to B \in \mathcal{L}(E)$. It is then straightforward to see that $(A_n, B_n) \to (A,B)$ for $N_2$.

Now we check that $F$ is complete for $N_1$. To do this, I use the inequality you say you've proven. This implies that if $(A_n,B_n)$ is Cauchy for $N_1$ then it is Cauchy for $N_2$ and hence by the same argument as before, $A_n, B_n$ are both Cauchy in $\mathcal{L}(E)$. Hence, we are again in the situation where $A_n \to A$ and $B_n \to B$ in $\mathcal{L}(E)$. Then 
\begin{align}
N_1(A_n - A, B_n - B)^2 &\leq \|(A_n - A)^* (A_n - A)\| + \|(B_n - B)^* (B_n - B)\|
\\& = \|A_n - A\|^2 + \|B_n - B\|^2 \to 0 
\end{align}
as $n \to \infty$.

Hence $F$ is a Banach space under either of $N_1$ and $N_2$. The inequality you have then shows that $\operatorname{Id}: (F, N_1) \to (F,N_2)$ is a continuous linear bijection and hence by the open mapping theorem has continuous inverse. This implies the existence of the desired constant.

Comment: Thank you very much for your idea. Just I hope to find $\alpha$ explicitly.

Comment: In future, this kind of thing is definitely a detail you should include in the question before someone takes the effort to answer it.

Comment: Yes you are right. Sorry. But your answer is very important to me.

Comment: Is there some reason you expect to be able to find an explicit value of $\alpha$ and particularly need one? Also, it might be helpful if you include your proof that $N_2 \leq N_1$.

Comment: Why isn't the proof of Theorem 2.1. given just an answer to this question?

Comment: The proof and the notation in the paper are not very clear. So, I thought perhaps there is an elementary proof.

Comment: The proof that $\alpha = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ works given seems (surprisingly) elementary to me. It's the part of Theorem 2.1. up to "on the other hand". You have $N_2 = \|\cdot\|_e$ and $N_1 = \| [ \cdot, \cdot] \|$. You then only have to follow a few lines of straightforward manipulations which use standard notations. You should try to do that and if there is some point you don't understand then you should post a question that asks about that specific point rather than for a whole proof.

Comment: I have posted a new question about the sharpness of the constant $\alpha$. Have you seen it? I need your help. Thanks a lot.